# Storing 9 bits in the file

Tags: c++

So I need to write algorithm which load the binary file and prefix every byte with one extra bit.

So if this is my binary file opened in "Binary editor":

0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0

0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

After processing i will have:

**1** 0 1 0 0 0 0 0

0 **0** 0 0 0 1 0 0

0 0 **1** 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 **1** 0 0 1 0

1 0 0 0 **0** 0 1 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

What "tool" can I use in c++ to achieve this goal ?

Comment: Bit shifting is your primary tool here. Then, every 8 bytes of input, output 9 bytes. Don't forget the final byte if the input size isn't divisible by 8. This should help.

Comment: Please be a bit clearer about what you want, and also post the code you tried all ready...

Comment: @Caribou I think he means which part of the language C++ to use, that's why he put "tools" in quotes (I guess).

Comment: @leemes yeah I'm grumpy today should probably not be looking here - I have my own coding nightmare to deal with :(

Comment: @Caribou me too, but sometimes it's a nice variety to look on SO. :)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like something `boost::dynamic_bitset` could be good at.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `vector<uint8_t>` and a lot of bit twiddling operators (`<<`, `>>`, `&`, `|` etc.). I might use a `vector<uint16_t>` to hold the 9-bit values as an intermediate step, depending on how hard I wanted to work.

Comment: Thanks, this was my plan too, i was willing that there is some more elegant tool :)

Comment: If you want to find something more elegant I would look for a 'streaming' class that can read and write arbitrary numbers of bits. I'm sure someone will have written that before, perhaps in boost?